# Run and include output of matlab code in document

Tags: input, matlab-prettifier

I want to run a matlab program and include the output in my document. To do this, I'm trying to combine `\input` and `matlab-prettifier`. This is what I tried:

```tex
\begin{lstlisting}[
  style      = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle = \mlttfamily,
  escapechar = `
]
`\input|"matlab -batch MyProgram"`
\end{lstlisting}
```

This doesn't work if the output contains unescaped characters like underscores, giving this error:

```
/test/test.tex:13: Extra }, or forgotten $.
<recently read> \egroup
```

I think this is strange, because I am able to have those characters if I type the output manually. How can I achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: I would use the `lstinputlisting{..}` form specifying `|matlab...` as the filename.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not know I could use that "file name" elsewhere! This works.

Comment: as you have tested and i haven't can you self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David pointed out, you can simply use the `|"matlab -batch MyProgram"` file name in `\lstinputlisting`. Thus the working result is:

```
\lstinputlisting[
  style      = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle = \mlttfamily,
]{|"matlab -batch MyProgram"}
```